# Isabelle function to find the longest sequence of members of a relation

Tags: isabelle

I have a relation R :: w => w => bool that is both transitive an irreflexive.

I have the axiom Ax1: "finite {x::w. True}". Therefore, for each x there is always a longest sequence of wn R ... R w2 R w1 R x.

I need a function F:: w => nat, that -for a given x - gives back the "lenght" of this sequence (or 0 if there is no y such that xRy). How would I go about building one in isabelle.

Also: Is Ax1 a good way to axiomatize the "finiteness of type w" or is there a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a more idiomatic way of writing `{x::w. True}` is `UNIV :: w set`. I suggest writing `finite (UNIV :: w set)`, or possibly using the `finite` type class, although that might make your theorem more difficult to apply because you need a `finite` instance for your type. I think it's not really necessary or helpful for your use case.

I then suggest the following approach:

1. Define an inductive predicate (using `inductive`) on lists of type `w list` stating that the first element is `x` and for each two successive list elements `y` and `z`, `R y z` holds, i.e. the list is an ascending chain w.r.t. `R`.
2. Show that any list that is such a chain must have distinct elements (cf. `distinct :: 'a list ⇒ bool`).
3. Show that there are finitely many `distinct` lists over a finite set.
4. Use the `Max` operator to find the biggest `n` such that there exists a list of length `n` that is an ascending chain w.r.t. `R`. That this works should be easy since there is at least one such chain, and you've already shown that there are only finitely many chains.

Comment: Thanks for takin the time to answer on a sunday. Do you have any suggestion how to efficently prove 3.? I feel like it should be relatively easy but I can´ t quite figure out how to  best do it.

Comment: Well, how would you do it informally on paper?